# Activate Monitor

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hotkeys

I have a laptop with 2 monitors attached, which worked until I hit ctrl + alt + F1, which is apparently a graphics hotkey. It is a hotkey combination in the software I was using and has never had any effect on the graphics before. The secondary monitor is now disabled. I have tried to enable it, using the same hotkeys,  but then the laptop monitor is disabled. How do I get all 3 monitors enabled. Windows 8, Intel Graphics driver v 10.18.10.3621.

Comment: What Operating system are you running (Windows 8, Windows 10, etc.)? What Graphics provider do you have? And what driver version do you have installed on your system? Well regardless, you should be able to enable the monitors using system settings.

Comment: Windows 8. Intel graphics. That's the problem- I can't enable the monitor using system settings. I either get the secondary monitor or the primary (laptop) monitor.

Comment: The next question, does your graphics card support multiple monitors? It might only support one at a time or only two. Can you also include the  model of the card along with the driver version you have installed?

Comment: It worked until I hit the hotkey combination of ctrl + alt + F1, so yes it does support multiple monitors.. Intel HD Graphics family, driver v 10.18.10.3621.

Comment: Edit your question to add the additional information you have added as a comment.

Comment: @Mary have you tried using the Intel Graphics Control Center? I believe Windows 8 automatically installs it...

Comment: I looked in the Intel Graphics control center and could not find any option for enabling the monitor. You can bet I if I ever get this fixed, I will save the profile!

Comment: Pressing the 'Windows Key + P' should give the dialog to select single monitor setup or multi-monitor setups. What does happen when you change these?

Comment: Finally got it figured out. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing the 'Windows Key + P' should give the dialog to select single monitor setup or multi-monitor setups. You may have reconfigured the video output so set it to "Extend" and check if that resolves this problem.
[image: Monitor setup Dialog]